# Why is laravel push giving me a error 1364: Field 'question_entity_id' doesn't have a default value?

Tags: php, laravel-5, post, eloquent

I'm very new to Laravel (this is my first time using it) and I'm trying to store some data that I made in a post request to my api. I keep on getting a General error: 1364 Field 'question_entity_id' doesn't have a default value.

I'm trying to use Laravel's `push` method to save the `itemBank` model and all it's relationships I define below but I get the error above. I've tried manually setting foreign_key relationships like `$itemBank->question_entity_id = $questionEntity->id' but this gives me the same error. I'm specifically trying to figure out why question_entity_id isn't getting filled (I know that the error could be resolved by making the field nullable or giving question_entity_id a default value).

Here are the relevant models:

```
class ItemBank extends Model
{
    // table name
    protected $table = "item_bank";

    // do no use default timestamp fields
    public $timestamps = false;

    // item_bank relationships to other Models/tables

    public function questionEntity() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\QuestionEntity', 'id', 'question_entity_id');
    }

    public function optionEntity() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OptionEntity', 'item_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tagItemRel() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\TagItemRel', 'item_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

```
class QuestionEntity extends Model
{
    // table name
    protected $table = 'question_entity';

    // disable default timestamps
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function itemBank() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ItemBank', 'id', 'question_entity_id');
    }
}
```

Here is the code where I'm trying to store my data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $itemBank = new ItemBank();

        //save question body text
        $questionEntity = new QuestionEntity();
        $questionEntity->question = $data['questionBody'];
        $itemBank->questionEntity()->save($questionEntity);

        // save correct answer
        $itemBank->correct_answers = $data['correctAnswer'];

        //save question options
        $choices = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
        //$optionEntities = [];
        foreach($choices as $choice) {
            $optionEntity = new OptionEntity();
            $optionEntity->choice = $data['choice' . $choice];
            $optionEntity->choice_label = $choice;
            $optionEntity->itemBank()->associate($itemBank);
        }
        //$itemBank->optionEntity()->saveMany($optionEntities);

        //create new ItemTag Model
        $itemTag = new ItemTag();
        $itemTag->tag_name = $data['topic'];

        //create new TagItemRel Model
        $tagItemRel = new TagItemRel();
        $tagItemRel->itemTag()->save($itemTag);
        $tagItemRel->itemBank()->associate($itemBank);

        $itemBank->push();
        return $itemBank;
    }
```

Here are the relevant migration files:

```
QuestionEntity:
Schema::create('question_entity', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('question', 500);
        });
```

```
ItemBank:
Schema::create('item_bank', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_entity_id');
            $table->string('correct_answers', 1);

            $table->foreign('question_entity_id')->references('id')->on('question_entity');
        });
```

Comment: Hi Kumalo. Your error-message is clear: You have a field `question_entity_id` in your table 'item_bank' and it is not nullable, and does not have a default value. Your code does not fill this field, but tries to save a record anyhow. This causes this error. To fix it, either make the field nullable( if it makes sence) or define a default value for the field in your table, or make sure your code fills the field with a proper id. Maybe you can show the table definitions? That would greatly help with the advice we can give you.

Comment: @RobBiermann sorry I should have been more clear in my question. I'm trying to figure out why my code is not filling the code with a proper id. I've added the definitions you requested.

Comment: Fairly important: Your relationship definition has the keys the wrong way around. `return $this->hasOne('App\QuestionEntity', 'id', 'question_entity_id');` needs to be  `return $this->hasOne('App\QuestionEntity', 'question_entity_id', 'id');`

Answer (score 0):

Add `question_entity_id` in your `ItemBank` model, like this.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'question_entity_id',
];
```

So your `ItemBank` model will look like this.

```
class ItemBank extends Model
{
    // table name
    protected $table = "item_bank";
    protected $fillable = [
    'question_entity_id','correct_answers'
];
```

Comment: Fillable is not required if you do not use an array to fill the models member fields.